# Is it possible to remove a micro-USB port and replace with a USB-C port

Tags: usb-device, usb-c

## Convert from micro-USB port to USB-C port (just to update the shape, not the capabilities)

I have a fairly old bicycle computer which uses a micro-USB port for charging and data transfer. This system works perfectly well, but I'm frustrated that an increasing number of the other devices that I carry or use when cycling (lights, phone, GoPro, headphones) use the newer USB-C port. I'd like to convert my old bicycle computer to USB-C for convenience so I only need to carry one cable when I go on trips rather than faff around with a few (I've even got an old bike light that uses mini-USB so that's yet another cable for the pocket).

To be clear, I'm aware there are differences in the capabilities of these two standards, and I'm not looking to reproduce the fast-charging or data transfer speeds of USB-C (I'm aware that's more complicated than just the shape of the port). I'm just trying to make the old device safely accept a USB-C cable for the same functions it currently performs through micro-USB.

Ideally, I don't want to have an external converter, I'd like to be able to just solder in a new port and close up the casing so it's still water-resistant.

### My Questions

- Is there some obvious reason why this is not possible.
- If it is possible, is it as simple as just soldering the old wires to the micro-USB port to some points on a new USB-C port?
- If it's not possible, can you point me in the right direction so I can understand the difficulties?

### Context

I have a background in engineering, but do not specialise in electronics. I'll understand most jargon you throw at me, but I hope you will forgive my obvious lack on knowledge on USB designs.

Comment: No solution you arrive at will be better, using any function of optimization (time, money, reliability,...) than spending a few dollars on a new bicycle computer.

Comment: Just use a converter usb-micro to USB-C (?).

Comment: Alright, thanks all. Sounds like more faff than it's worth. I'll keep my trusty bike computer as it is and just put up with carrying an extra cable on longer journeys.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is technically possible.

In practice, you are faced with more mechanical issues than electrical. How to make the connector and additional components fit and how to make it waterproof like the original.

And no, it is not as simple as changing one connector with another. Additional resistors are required to make the USB interface detectable by computer. Not more than a few resistors, but this question how to switch to USB-C has been asked and answred before so I won't duplicate the details here.

Comment: Alright, cheers for that @Justme . On balance, sounds like I'd be better of just leaving it be.

Regarding the resistors you mention, could you direct me to somewhere I could read about the potential circuit design? Purely academic interest.